# Print all Unique Values in a Python Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm struggling with a minor problem in Python (my program is in version 3.2.3 right now).

I have a dictionary that looks like this (this is just an example, actually taken from another post here):

```
[
    {"abc": "movies"},
    {"abc": "sports"},
    {"abc": "music"},
    {"xyz": "music"},
    {"pqr": "music"},
    {"pqr": "movies"},
    {"pqr": "sports"},
    {"pqr": "news"},
    {"pqr": "sports"},
]
```

I want to simply print() a list of unique values, eliminating duplicates. At the end of this list, I would like to print the number of unique values in the dictionary:

```
movies
sports
music
news

4
```

Any help is appreciated. There are some other posts here I found that were somewhat related, but I don't know Python well enough to apply it to this specific problem.

Comment: you have a *list* of dictionaries.

Answer (score 65):

Use `set` here as they only contain unique items.

```
>>> lis = [{"abc":"movies"}, {"abc": "sports"}, {"abc": "music"}, {"xyz": "music"}, {"pqr":"music"}, {"pqr":"movies"},{"pqr":"sports"}, {"pqr":"news"}, {"pqr":"sports"}]
>>> s = set( val for dic in lis for val in dic.values())
>>> s 
set(['movies', 'news', 'music', 'sports'])
```

Loop over this set to get the expected output:

```
for x in s:                                
    print x
print len(s)   #print the length of set after the for-loop
... 
movies
news
music
sports
4
```

This line `s = set( val for dic in lis for val in dic.values())` is roughly equivalent to:

```
s = set()
for dic in lis:
   for val in dic.values():
      s.add(val)
```

Comment: Points for explaining the nested list comprehension.

Comment: That nested list is crazy, would have **never** thought of that.

Answer (score 31):

You can exploit the properties of `set` for this purpose; each element is unique and duplicates will be ignored.

```
uniqueValues = set(myDict.values())
```

By using `set` in this way, duplicate elements returned from `.values()` will be discarded. You can then print them as follows:

```
for value in uniqueValues:  
    print(value)  
print(len(uniqueValues))
```

Comment: This doesn't work if the values of myDict are dictionaries as well

Answer (score 12):

Use a `set()`:

```
from itertools import chain

unique_values = set(chain.from_iterable(d.values() for d in dictionaries_list))
for value in unique_values:
    print(value)

print(len(unique_values))
```

Use `.itervalues()` on Python 2 for a little more efficiency. Because you have a *list* of dictionaries, we need to pull out the values from each of those dictionaries first; I used [`itertools.chain.from_iterable()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) with a generator expression to list all values in a sequence:

```
>>> for value in set(chain.from_iterable(d.values() for d in dictionaries_list)):
...     print(value)
... 
news
sports
movies
music
```

The alternative is to use nested loops in the generator expression:

```
>>> for value in set(v for d in dictionaries_list for v in d.values()):
...     print(value)
... 
news
sports
movies
music
```

Answer (score 7):

```
dict = {'511':'Vishnu','512':'Vishnu','513':'Ram','514':'Ram','515':'sita'}
list =[] # create empty list
for val in dict.values(): 
  if val in list: 
    continue 
  else:
    list.append(val)

print list
```

Comment: A `set` would be more efficient for this. Using the `in` operator is not as efficient for lists.