# how to print elements which occur only once in a list, without counting

Tags: python

If I have a dictionary {key : [a b c c d]}  and I want to print only the unique values corresponding to each key (In this case, (a,b,d)) what is the most efficient way to do this apart from just looping through each element and keeping a count of it?

Comment: Don't you mean `(a,b,c,d)` in this case?

Comment: Is this a repeat of [Print all Unique Values in a Python Dictionary](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17218139) is it?

Comment: No I meant exactly printing only (a,b,d). I don't want to print c.

Comment: I think OP's question was pretty clear and explicit. No counting, and only elements which are unique (occur only once). Not each element in the list, excluding duplicates.

Comment: Can't be done without counting, unless you have more restrictions on the list. Is it guaranteed to be sorted/partitioned?

Comment: @Rhymoid I beg to differ 8)

Comment: With such (strange) requirements, it's always useful to state why you have them. What's the problem with using a `Counter`?

Comment: @2rs2ts: I think counting in the lattice of `[0, 1, many]` under `<=` is unavoidable. For instance, `a` is not unique in `[a, b, c, d, a]`, but you always need to keep track of the fact that `a` already occurs in the list (regardless of the way you combine the sub-answers). Not so with lists where equal elements are always found together, then you just have to count the length of each run, for which you only need constant space.

Comment: @Rhymoid I agree, but, it's not that it's not *possible*. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If elements are sorted as in your example; you could use [`itertools.groupby()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

print " ".join([k for k, group in groupby(d['key']) if len(list(group)) == 1])
# -> a b d
```

Comment: @vkaul11, if you go with this, you can just get the list by removing the `" ".join( ... )` part.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian for your tip.

Answer (score 2):

One option, use [collections.Counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
from collections import Counter
d = {'k': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd']}
c = Counter(d['k'])
print [k for k in c if c[k] == 1]
['a', 'b', 'd']
```

Comment: If you read the source code for `Counter`, it just does "looping through each element and keeping a count of it", which the OP didn't want.

Comment: @1_CR thanks for understanding my question at least. I got downvotes from people who did not even understand my question.

Comment: @vkaul11 I upvoted to compensate. I think your question, while hard to find a use case for it, is quite legitimate and clearly worded. Python devs on SO just like to use Counter and sets. :P

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Counter` from `collections`:

```
>>> d = {'key': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd']}
>>> 
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> 
>>> new_dict = Counter(d['key'])
>>> new_dict
Counter({'c': 2, 'a': 1, 'b': 1, 'd': 1})
>>> [elem for elem in new_dict.keys() if new_dict[elem] == 1]
['a', 'b', 'd']
```

Comment: OP wants to find the elements which are only contained once.

Comment: @2rs2ts. Yeah got confused. Updated answer.

Comment: I appreciate it, and I hate to be pedantic, but OP also asked for no counting.

Answer (score 0):

Not using a Counter:

```
unique = []
for i, val in enumerate(d['key']):
    if item not in d['key'][i+1:] and item not in d['key'][:i]:
        unique.append(item)
```

Using a generator comprehension:

```
unique = list((d['key'][i] for i in range(len(d['key'])) if d['key'][i] not in d['key'][i+1:] and d['key'][i] not in d['key'][:i]))
```

Comment: Pretty innovative solution I must say.

Comment: This algorithm is O(n²), which is even less efficient than than using a Counter, which is O(n).

Comment: What about sorting before so you can only check the next and previous value?

Comment: @Maxime Well, sorting adds an O(n log n) time complexity to whatever else you're going to do.

Comment: @Aya what makes my first part O(n^2)? Use of enumerate?

Comment: Yes, sorry, it was not an answer to your comment. You are most probably right, Counter sounds to be a better solution anyway. Just saying that complexity would be still better than O(n^2) and still no counting as asking by OP.

Comment: @2rs2ts `item not in d['key'][i+1:]` does an O(n) search of the list.

Comment: @Aya ah, fair enough! Quite an oversight of mine. I'd personally use counting anyway, but, it's not my place to tell OP what to do instead, but rather just tell him how to do what he's asking.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the list is sorted:

```
>>> L = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5]
>>> [e for i, e in enumerate(L) if e == L[i-1] and i < len(L)-1 and not e == L[i+1]]
[1, 4]
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use a `set()` to find all the unique elements in each list.

```
for key in mydict:
    uniques = set(mydict[key])
```

Comment: Again, I only want to print the unique elements and not print the duplicate elements at all. Here you will print all elements though you will print the duplicates only once.

Comment: What you want is to print only the elements that appear once. This is different from printing a list of the unique elements.

Answer (score -2):

In Python, you can leverage a set (a set can not have repeating elements) to find the unique elements in each key and then turn the set back into a list

```
for key in dict:
    print list(set(dict[key]))
```

Comment: I want to print only the elements that are unique like I said above if there is (a,b,c,c,d) in the list I only want to print (a,b,d) and not print c.