# Getting a list of unique words (i.e., not duplicates) in Python

Tags: python

I have a list with several words and I want to print the unique words from that list. With "unique" words I mean words that only appear once in my original list. That is, if a word appears twice (or more than twice), then it shouldn't be printed.

Here's my list of words:

```
my_list = ["door", "table", "door", "chair", "couch", "door", "table", "closet"]
```

And here's the code I've tried so far:

```
print(set(my_list))
```

However, `set` prints a list with ALL the words, though there aren't duplicates. That is: `door, table, chair, couch, closet`. However, what I want is a list like `chair, couch, closet`(because they are the ones that appear only once in the list).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to print elements which occur only once in a list, without counting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17218789/how-to-print-elements-which-occur-only-once-in-a-list-without-counting)

Answer (score 1):

Not a neat way to achieve what you want, but still a good workaround, by using `Counter`. Counter will count how many times each item appear in a list.

```
from collections import Counter
my_list = ["door", "table", "door", "chair", "couch", "door", "table", "closet"]
my_list_count = Counter(my_list) # Counter({'door': 3, 'table': 2, 'chair': 1, 'closet': 1, 'couch': 1})

# Unique item have count = 1
print([xx for xx in my_list_count if my_list_count[xx] == 1])
# Results: ['chair', 'closet', 'couch']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like -

```
res = [x for x in my_list if my_list.count(x) == 1]
```

It will return list of elements that occur once.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Counter` for this, which will create a dictionary with each unique word as the key and the respective occurrence count as the corresponding value. Then iterate through the dictionary to find the key with the value of `1`. The sample code is as follows:

```
from collections import Counter

my_list = ["door", "table", "door", "chair", "couch", "door", "table", "closet"]

count_all = Counter(my_list)
for key, value in count_all.items():
    if 1 == value:
        print key
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a short snippet on how you can go about it.

```
from collections import Counter
count_dict = Counter(my_list)

for k, v in count_dict.items():
    if v == 1:
        print(k)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is something you can try

```
def keep_unique(array):
    counts = {}
    for e in array:
        if e not in counts:
            counts[e] = 0
        counts[e] += 1
    return [k for (k, v) in counts.items() if v == 1]

print(keep_unique(["door", "table", "door", "chair", "couch", "door", "table", "closet"]))
```

The `keep_unique` method counts the number of occurrences of each element and then returns only the ones which appear only once.

Answer (score 0):

A solution without `Counter` could be to sort your list and check if surrounding words are different:

```
my_list = ["door", "table", "door", "chair", "couch", "door", "table", "closet"]
my_list.sort()

unique = [word for i, word in enumerate(my_list) if my_list[i - 1] != word and my_list[i + 1] != word] 
print(unique)
# ['chair', 'closet', 'couch']
```