# how can I checking only a spefic dict key for unique values?

Tags: python

I am trying to have the same behaviour, but I want to check if `url` dict contains unique values instead of checking the complete dict.

```
def unique(data):
    result = {}
    for key, value in data.items():
        new_list = []
        for item in value:
            if item not in new_list:
                new_list.append(item)
        result[key] = new_list
        return result



games = { 
   "games":[ 
      { 
         "city":"Santa Monica, CA",
         "company":"rockstar",
         "date":{ 
            "display":"24 days ago",
            "timestamp":1570721082
         },
         "game":"akakkak",
         "challenge":"leel",
         "url":"https://www.game.com/12757a575/aaashs/2222"
      },{ 
         "city":"Santa Monica, CA",
         "company":"rockstar",
         "date":{ 
            "display":"24 days ago",
            "timestamp":1570721082
         },
         "game":"akak2kak",
         "challenge":"leel",
         "url":"https://www.game.com/12757a575/aaashs/2222"
      }
   ]
}

print(unique(games))
```

I expect the output of `"url":"https://www.game.com/12757a575/aaashs/2222"` without having the same value in the same key

Comment: See the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17218139/print-all-unique-values-in-a-python-dictionary

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a seprate list of urls to keep track of each unique url like so:

```
def unique(data):
    result = {}
    for key, value in data.items():
        new_list = []
        url_list = []
        for item in value:
            if item['url'] not in url_list:
                new_list.append(item)
                url_list.append(item['url'])
        result[key] = new_list
        return result
```

Comment: I thought it will keep the same behaviour checking all content of dict, but I only want to check url key values