# How to get all the distinct values in a dictionary

Tags: python

I have a dictionary like this: `d = {"name": "john", "surname": "smith", "nickname: "john"}`

I want to get all unique values, i.e: `["john", "smith"]`

I have see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17218139/print-all-unique-values-in-a-python-dictionary) question which does the same a for list of dictionaries, and I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7002429/how-can-i-extract-all-values-from-a-dictionary-in-python) question which uses `values()` but it does not return the unique list of values.

Comment: `set(d.values())`?

Comment: This question is marked as duplicate, but the duplicate question does not return **distinct values**

Comment: A better duplicate would be this: [Print all Unique Values in a Python Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17218139/print-all-unique-values-in-a-python-dictionary).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can convert the value of a dict to a set to remove the duplicate and pass it back to a list `list(set(d.values()))`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `set`

```
unique = list(set(d.values()))
```